# Show Rows even if joined table is empty?

Tags: mysql

If I retrieve a list of venues with their closing times from another table like this:

```
$fullDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$query="SELECT
venues.ID,
venues.VENUE_NAME,
locations.LOCATION,
hrs.opening_day,
hrs.opening_time,
hrs.closing_time
FROM venues
INNER JOIN venue_types
ON venues.VENUE_TYPE = venue_types.ID
INNER JOIN locations
ON venues.VENUE_LOCATION = locations.ID
INNER JOIN hours_of_operation hrs
  on hrs.venue_id = venues.id
     and ((hrs.opening_day=date_format('$fullDate' - INTERVAL (closing_time<opening_time and time('$fullDate')<closing_time) DAY, '%a')))
GROUP BY venues.VENUE_NAME";
```

I get a result of the venues where I have already specified their opening/closing times for a particular day in `hours_of_operation`. How would I show all of the venues irrespective of whether the `hours_of_operation` row for that day is empty for that particular day?

Thanks! :)

Comment: You have no aggregating functions in this query so GROUP BY is inappropriate. I suspect that you meant to use SELECT DISTINCT...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use LEFT JOIN:

```
...
LEFT JOIN hours_of_operation hrs
...
```